# Adding forecast values to original df

Tags: r, dataframe, forecasting

I have a dataframe, df containing 25 variables.

I want to forecast one day value for each variable using forecast package.

```
df # original df

df2 <- df2 <- apply(df, 2, function (x) forecast(tbats(ts(x,frequency=365)), h=1))
$GOOG.Volume
         Point Forecast    Lo 80   Hi 80  Lo 95   Hi 95
3.142466        1654547 920711.4 2765229 650538 3544211

$GOOG.Adjusted
         Point Forecast   Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
3.142466       530.7542 521.654 540.0065 516.8974 544.9667

$Avg_vol_10
         Point Forecast   Lo 80   Hi 80   Lo 95   Hi 95
3.142466        1889756 1761678 2027142 1697429 2103866
```

.....

```
> df2$GOOG.Volume
         Point Forecast    Lo 80   Hi 80  Lo 95   Hi 95
3.142466        1654547 920711.4 2765229 650538 3544211
> df2$GOOG.Volume$mean
Time Series:
Start = c(3, 53) 
End = c(3, 53) 
Frequency = 365 
[1] 1654547
attr(,"biasadj")
[1] FALSE
```

how, can I append, the mean value of all these 1- day forecast to my data frame df.

Thanks

This is my current dataframe,

[sample df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPfEp.png)
I want to add the mean value  of th single forecast of each column at the end of this dataframe.

link to dataframe. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MkAHU-VcVpjQelsMOLaNoHPFwH2mbzig

final df

```
col_a    col_a    col_a    col_a    col_a
all present values, 

last row, we appended  (rbind ) with forecasted means

predictions of all columns


pred_cola   pred_colb   pred_colc   pred_cold


This is my requirement.
```

Comment: please provide the a sample `dput` of your data frame? Also, show us the expected result. Few lines will do.

Comment: @YOLO I have added sample df and I just want to add the mean of forecast for each variable from df2 at last in each column of df.

Comment: but mean is a single value ? What do you mean by appending ? Do you want to add new columns with single mean value duplicated in all rows ?

Comment: No, I wan to add the single value for each variable forecast to the variable in the data frame itself.

Comment: please show the expected result. Hard to imagine how would the final df would look like, a few rows will suffice.

Comment: @YOLO I have added the final df explained, it is clearly obvious what I want to do, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal example of what you want to do:

```
# sample data, replace this with yours
df <- data.table(google=runif(n = 10, 10,100),
                 apple=runif(n=10, 10, 200),
                 shell=runif(n=10, 20, 400))

# apply forecast function
df2 <- apply(df, 2, function (x) forecast(tbats(ts(x,frequency=365)), h=1))

# get mean values in a separate vector
stock_cols <- colnames(df)
get_mean_values <- sapply(stock_cols, function(x) df2[[x]]$mean, USE.NAMES = F)

# convert mean values vector to data frame
get_mean_df <- t(data.frame(get_mean_values))
colnames(get_mean_df) <- stock_cols
row.names(get_mean_df) <- NULL

## rbind values in the original dataframe
df <- rbind(df, get_mean_df)

print(df)

     google     apple     shell
 1: 99.52935 170.18530 387.77822
 2: 46.12997  41.67531 265.41992
 3: 90.60817 155.16369  94.59444
 4: 88.91726 108.59824 155.72855
 5: 36.68363  61.81021 214.94687
 6: 21.93327  75.20860 355.53876
 7: 33.93198 143.96431  78.01367
 8: 10.51548 122.39171 107.57541
 9: 83.76416  99.18202  81.93566
10: 25.71955  73.91156 253.45181
11: 56.22397 106.50459 206.37342 ## this rows shows the mean value.
```